# How can i invoke two instances of two different versions of jvm or same version of jvm in a single dos prompt?

Tags: java, jvm

if i had installed two versions of java(jdk 7 & jdk 8) how can i invoke these two instance of jvm in a single dos prompt simultaneously?
If a single version is installed how can i invoke two or more instance of same jvm simultaneously in my RAM?

Comment: I don't think that its possible...

Comment: Pretty sure you can't have multiple processes launched within one prompt

Comment: if we change the temporary path of other java tool at the time of the previos java tool is executing.....can it be then possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one default version in your path, however you can also specify any version you need explicitly. e.g.

On my windows laptop I have four versions installed and I can run any one I want.

```
c:\>"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin\java" -version
java version "1.7.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_60-b19)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.60-b09, mixed mode)

c:\>"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\java" -version
java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)

c:\>"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java" -version
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)

c:\>"c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java" -version
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

The number of versions you can have is only limited by your disk space.

Comment: My question is that can i run the instances of these version's JVM simultaneousley?.....If i could then can it be possible in a single dos prompt......?

Comment: @ManikArora there is no reason  you can't run two programs at once even if they are different versions of the sane program unless you have so little memory you only have enough for one. You can run multiple programs from the same dos prompt even if the nane is the same by using the full path name of the program.